# How to check the numbering pattern of questions in java

Tags: java, database, arraylist, split

I am a beginner in the java programming language. 
However, I am faced with this challenge, which I have googled severally, but can't find my expected solution. 
The problem is, supposing you have a list of multiple choice questions, which may be numbered either by numbers or alphanumeric, how can I detect the numbering system, and split it from that point.

Example:

```
      1) What is your name?
         a. Eben
         b. Derick

      2. How old are you?
         a) 18 years
         b) 20 years 

      3] Who is your best friend? a. Programmers b. Scientist

     (4) What is your dream profession? A) Software Engineering B) Computer Science
```

Now, I want to find out if there is either **1)** or **2.** or **(1)** or **a.** or **b)** or **(b)** or **A.** or **B)** or **(B)** or **3]**, and use that to split and save the question or answers in a database.
My advanced appreciation to all cherished members!

Comment: This could get very complicated if the questions or answers could contain text that might be mistaken for a question/answer labels.  But if you can make certain simplifying assumptions, the task becomes much easier.  Will you be expected to deal with anything more complicated than the given example and explanations?

Comment: But I should add that if that example _is_ the most complicated thing you'll have to handle, the solution, though far from trivial, is well within reach.

Comment: Where are the questions being read from? A file, A single string? An array of strings?

Comment: If you are responsible for generating such text data, you might want to serialize it in JSON or XML: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Comment: @DevilHnd The questions are being read from an array of strings. Thank you for your concern

Comment: @Kevin Anderson, Sure, you are very right, it could get truly complicated if text might be mistaken for label. However, I expect such question or answer labels to either begin a line or right after question mark or a full stop. I might be wrong though, but I am thinking of first splitting the strings based on label patterns, and then use nested or recursive loops, which I don't know how to implement it as a beginner in the java language.

Comment: I think you probably mean _nested_ loops (i.e., loop-within-a-loop) rather than "recursive", but whatever you call them, you're going to need them eventually in your programming life, so the sooner you start getting comfortable with them the better.  Anyway, your approach sounds like a good one, and the assumption that a question will start at the beginning of a line makes things rather simpler. For help recognizing label patterns, check out Java's [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) capabilities if you're not already familiar.